# ContextMenu doesn't inherits resource style

Tags: wpf, styles, contextmenu

I have a button and this button has a context menu. When left-clicking on the button, I set ContextMenu.IsOpen property to true using button click trigger.
My problem is as follow -
As long as I don't right click on the button, the context menu doesn't inherits the style I defined in the resources of the window.
I searched it up and found out the context menu's style only initialized after right-clicking it.
How can I force the style to initialize even when I don't right-click it? (I can't set the style of the context menu hard-coded because I want it to change automatically and easily when changing the theme, without separated maintain each context menu I have on my code).
Thanks!

The XAML:

`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Content="Click Me!" Width="80" Height="50">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <CheckBox Content="Include First Option"/>
                            </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <CheckBox Content="Include Second Option"/>
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

'

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer I've been looking for -
ContextMenu is a special control - it doesn't a part of the window it is defined in, but a separated window. After right-clicking it, it checks who called it and initializes the inheritable properties. But when opening it in a different way - it doesn't know who opened it.
The answer -
In order for the default style of the context menu to be override, the style has to be defined in the App.xaml with no key.

The App.xaml resources should look like:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

create your own complete style (this here is only a simple sample) and use it with a special key.

```
<Style x:Key="CustomContextMenu"
        TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Green" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="#888888" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope"
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="HasDropShadow"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow"
                                Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                Property="Padding"
                                Value="0,3,0,3" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                Property="CornerRadius"
                                Value="4" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

usage

```
<Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource CustomContextMenu}">
        <MenuItem>
            <MenuItem.Header>
                <CheckBox Content="Include First Option" />
            </MenuItem.Header>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
            <MenuItem.Header>
                <CheckBox Content="Include Second Option" />
            </MenuItem.Header>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</Button.ContextMenu>
```

hope that helps!

[image]

Comment: It doesn't really solve my problem - if I do what you suggest, it means every time I change the theme I need to change all the context menu's style I have on my code manually, and that is not so maintenance friendly (I prefer using style with no key so it will just inherits the style, as any normal control). Any suggestions? Thanks anyway :)